# Signs of Grandi's series $1-1+1-1+1-1+\ldots$ in the real world?

Tags: mathematical-physics, regularization

I'm talking about the convergence of the series $1-1+1-1+1-1+\ldots$ to $1/2$. I was discussing with some friends (we study physics) and I argued that Cesaro summation is a fair extension of the common summation for infinite series. They told me that it was just a mathematical definition, but that it didn't mean it had applications to the real world. I put the example of Grandi's series mixed with the turned on/off lamp, but that is just a thought experiment.
My question is: is there any experiment where replacing Grandi's series by 1/2 explains the result or is Cesaro summation a mathematical definition and has no use in physics?

Comment: That series doesn't converge, period. You could say that it is Cesaro-convergent, if you want to, in which case it also Abel-convergent. I suspect that one can construct entire series of increasingly stronger convergence filters that can assign convergence values to divergent series that satisfy non-trivial criteria. For physics none of this matters because physical phenomena are not calculating any series, neither convergent nor divergent ones. Only our models of these phenomena do and if a model doesn't converge to the experimental/observational answer, then we need a better model.

Comment: To add to CuriousOne's comment: in physics/engineering, unless the value of the series from  $N+1$ to $\infty$ has a single, well-defined value, then we cannot get a useable approximation from the sum from 1 to N.

Comment: Wikipedia gives some use cases in physics : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occurrences_of_Grandi%27s_series